# How to count distinct logins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the distinct count of users logging in every day.

I want to add another column to know the distinct count of users logging in at least once for the past 7 days.

```
;WITH cte (login_date,  years, iso_week, months, emails) AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(a.login_time AS Date),
        DATEPART(YEAR, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(MONTH, a.login_time),
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.email) AS Total
    FROM 
        database.log AS a WITH(NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY 
        CAST(a.login_time AS Date),
        DATEPART(YEAR, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(MONTH, a.login_time)
)
```

Now if I try

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(emails) OVER (PARTITION BY years, iso_weeks
                      ORDER BY login_date
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS counts_week
FROM
    cte
```

This basically adds everyday logins to makeup a week but this is the opposite of what I want. it is not the sum of distinct email logins for 7 days, it is the unique emails who logs in within a week

So if I'm using three emails as example I should have in the column `emails_week` the following

```
+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+
| login_date | years | iso_week | months | emails | emails_week |
+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+
| 2018-12-07 |  2018 |       49 |     12 |      2 |           2 |
| 2018-12-08 |  2018 |       49 |     12 |      2 |           2 |
| 2018-12-09 |  2018 |       49 |     12 |      1 |           2 |
| 2018-12-10 |  2018 |       50 |     12 |      1 |           3 |
| 2018-12-11 |  2018 |       50 |     12 |      3 |           3 |
| 2018-12-12 |  2018 |       50 |     12 |      1 |           3 |
+------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide a sample output for it.

Comment: @AT-2017 just included  an outpput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's certain to be a prettier way to do this - but  - I've edited the SQL to check each week based on the ISO week number.  Basically, using the week number to determine the start and end dates for the distinct email counting. This new version uses multiple CTEs to first get the list of dates and their week number.  The second CTE(ldetails) no longer includes your group by on [login_time] Then I join this with the results against the week number.

Setup

```
Declare @tbl Table
(
login_time Datetime,
email VarChar(50)
)
Insert Into @tbl Values 
('2018-12-02','email@domain.com'),
('2018-12-02','emailyyyy@domain.com'),
('2018-12-07','emailxx@domain.com'),
('2018-12-07','emailzzz@domain.com'),
('2018-12-07','emailzzz@domain.com'),
('2018-11-07','email@domain.com'),
('2018-11-07','emailx@domain.com'),
('2018-12-01','email@domain.com'),
('2018-12-11','email@domain.com')
```

Query

```
;With ldates As
(
Select Cast(Login_time As Date) As Login_Date,Max(DATEPART(YEAR, login_time)) As [Year],Max(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, login_time)) As [Week] From @tbl
Group By Login_time
),

 ldetails As
(
    SELECT 
        --CAST(a.login_time AS Date) As lTime,
        DATEPART(YEAR, a.login_time) As [Year]
        ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, a.login_time) As [Week]
        ,DATEPART(MONTH, a.login_time) As [Month]
        ,Count (Distinct email) As tot
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT (Case When login_time Between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE()) And GetDate() Then email Else Null End)) AS Total

       ,Count(Distinct
        (Case When login_time Between  
          (DATEADD(DAY, (7 * (DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, login_time)-1)), Cast(DATEPART(YEAR, login_time) As Char(4)) + '-01-01' ))  And 
          (DATEADD(DAY, (7 * (DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, login_time)-1)) +7, Cast(DATEPART(YEAR, login_time) As Char(4)) + '-01-01' )) 
          Then email Else Null End
        )) AS Totalyy

    FROM @tbl AS a 
    GROUP BY 
        --CAST(a.login_time AS Date),
        DATEPART(YEAR, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, a.login_time),
        DATEPART(MONTH, a.login_time)
)
Select lDates.login_Date,ldetails.[Year],ldetails.[Week],ldetails.[Month],ldetails.tot,ldetails.Total,ldetails.Totalyy From ldetails 
Inner JOIN
lDates On ldetails.[Week] = lDates.[Week] And ldetails.[Year] = lDates.[Year]
```

Result

```
login_Date  Year    Week    Month   tot Total   Totalyy
2018-11-07  2018    45      11      2   0       2
2018-12-01  2018    48      12      2   0       2
2018-12-02  2018    48      12      2   0       2
2018-12-07  2018    49      12      2   2       2
2018-12-11  2018    50      12      1   1       1
```

Comment: You are using getdate() so it will always be the same thing. For your value ('2018-11-07','email@domain.com'), this should be 1 loging for the 7dayweek #45.

Comment: Hi Roger.  I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly.  Are you suggesting:        ,COUNT(DISTINCT (Case When login_time Between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE()) And GetDate() Then email Else Null End)) AS Total

Comment: Hi @level3looper. Why use getdate()? i need the distinct count of each week.

Comment: GetDate() with Date Add() is used as a range  for "7 days ago to today".  If you're saying 'each week' - then I'm not on the mark and maybe you're looking for a Calendar table to use.or another trick?

Comment: Yes each week of the year or any time period required.

Comment: Hi @RogerSteinberg, I modified the code to use the ISO week for the date range check.  Does this work?

Comment: the count of emails per ISO_Week should be the same for each row associated to that ISO_Week. See week 48 - you have Totalxx 1 and 2. It should be 2 and 2

Comment: On this revision, you'll see CTEs were used to first get the login dates with their week number.  Then it joins these results with the details. (The second CTE has the [login_time excluded from the Group By clause)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using COUNT(DISTINCT ...)?